# How to show a default message if no recently viewed products?

Tags: magento-1.8, theme, template

I am trying to show a message when there is no recently viewed products.

But after enabling Template Path Hints from the magento dashboard, I found that the reports/product_viewed.phtml is not even called if there is no recently viewed products.

Can anyone please help how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to `/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Block/Product/Viewed.phtml`
after this find for function

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (!$this->getCount()) {
        return '';
    }
    $this->setRecentlyViewedProducts($this->getItemsCollection());
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

and write your message in line number 79 inside return
for e.g.- return 'Your message';
It will show your message when there is no recently viewed products. try to overwrite the function.

Comment: You mean overwrite the function by creating custom module

Comment: yes,but you can also make changes in viewed.phtml file,it will not affect any another file just try it....